# isClicked() for ButtonType Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a form on a modal with 2 buttons of type submit. So depending on what button is clicked, the same function in a service will be accessed but with different parameters. What I want to do is keep the modal open when clicking on any of the buttons.

```
public function createFormExport(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        //...
        ->add('btn1', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Button 1'
        ))
        ->add('btn2', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Button 2'
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->get('btn1')->isClicked()) {
        $this
            ->getService()
            ->function($form->getData(), "bt1");
    } elseif ($form->get('btn2')->isClicked()) {
        $this
            ->getService()
            ->function($form->getData(), "btn2");
    }

    return $form->createView();

}
```

I'm getting data in the function in the service without problem but I want to prevent the page from reloading when I click on any of the button.

If for the buttons I use `ButtonType` rather than `SubmitType`, the function `isClicked()` is not recognised unfortunately.

Is there a way I can verify which button is clicked if I use `ButtonType` because if I use `SubmitType`, I will have to detect the button click in JS to prevent page reload and then generate a route in AJAX and read the data in the form and send it back in my controller. This really complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
//Controller
//return of your method called by the route
(...)
return new JsonResponse(['someData' => '123456789']);
```

Jquery :

```
   $("#btn1, #btn2").click(function () {
        var url = "";
        var formSerialize = $("#formAjax").serialize();
        // #formAjax is the id of your <form>
        $.post(url, formSerialize, function(response) {
                $('.anyClass').html(response.someData);
       }, 'JSON')
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
               //do something
    });
```